# reason for "RuntimeError (can't add a new key into hash during iteration)" from Mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Our application is a Rails application running on MongoDB via mongoid.  We are seeing this error intermittently:

```
RuntimeError (can't add a new key into hash during iteration)
…contrib-2.1.3/lib/rpm_contrib/instrumentation/mongo.rb:  17:in `instrument_with_newrelic_trace'
…d_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/mongo/cursor.rb: 391:in `send_initial_query'
…contrib-2.1.3/lib/rpm_contrib/instrumentation/mongo.rb:  33:in `refresh_with_newrelic_trace'
…d_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/mongo/cursor.rb:  75:in `next_document'
…ndled_gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/mongo/db.rb: 492:in `command'
…ms/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/mongo/collection.rb: 685:in `new_group'
…ms/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mongo-1.3.0/lib/mongo/collection.rb: 600:in `group'
…1/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/collections/master.rb:  19:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Master>'
….1/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/collections/retry.rb:  29:in `retry_on_connection_failure'
…1/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/collections/master.rb:  18:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Master>'
…uby/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/collection.rb:  21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Collection>'
…ngin/releases/20110902181215/app/models/stat_module.rb:  86:in `aggregate_team_stats'
….9.1/gems/mongoid-2.0.1/lib/mongoid/relations/proxy.rb: 111:in `method_missing'
```

It seems like it happens when I am running any sort of [MongoidModel].collection.group() command.  The stack trace seems to indicate that the problem is somewhere within mongo/mongoid internals. What's more, it is only a problem on our production environment, so it's very hard to isolate and debug.

We are using these gems:

- mongo 1.3.1
- mongoid 2.0.1

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 2):

After some further investigation, it looks like the newrelic 
rpm_contrib gem itself was the culprit.  Usually when I see that in a 
stack trace I just ignore it since newrelic is involved in logging 
errors, but in this case it was actually causing the error.  We 
happened to upgrade the gem to 2.1.4 yesterday afternoon because we thought 
newrelic was acting a bit flaky, which is about the time we stopped 
seeing errors in production.  Looking into the first line of the stack 
trace, that line newrelic code was modified to prevent race 
conditions, which jives with the RuntimeError. So, I'm going to assume 
this is fixed and is not in fact related to mongo itself.